# CREATE or ALTER when using replication

Tags: replication, sql-server-2017

I am using CREATE OR ALTER in the scripts for all of my views and stored procedures, as they are pushed frequently from a CD pipeline.  I am also using replication to push certain tables, views, and stored procedures to several SQL Server subscribers.  Recently, one of my remote devs noticed that  changes to views and stored procedures were not being replicated even after they have been added as articles.  From what I can tell, ALTER VIEW or ALTER PROCEDURE should both be triggering replication updates which led me to believe CREATE OR ALTER would operate in the same way. I ran some manual tests while watching the replication monitor and it only appears to be triggering the DDL change to subscribers when I use just ALTER, but not if I use CREATE OR ALTER.

Is this expected behavior?